# Toggle class during scroll function

Tags: jquery, function, scroll

If it possible to somehow write a snippet that during the scroll function on the window the body is appended with a class?

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('body').toggleClass('scrolling');
 });
```

If the user is scrolling then the body has a class of 'scrolling'. If the scroll is not currently happening, the body has no class.

The scroll function seems to rapidly fire with the function above.

Comment: +1, but define "scrolling"...

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/scroll/ for a working example. Unfortunately, it's easy to detect when scrolling starts but harder to know when it's stopped.

Comment: @Blazemonger. Yeah, this is what I meant, define when the user stopped scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a "scroll start" and "scroll end" pair like "mouse down" and "mouse up": the "scroll" event is more of a "scroll just occurred". You can set a timeout to clear your "scrolling" class if no scroll has happened for *n* milliseconds:

```
var scrollTimerId;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if (!scrollTimerId)
       $('body').addClass('scrolling');

    clearTimeout(scrollTimerId);
    scrollTimerId = setTimeout(function(){
        $('body').removeClass('scrolling');
           scrollTimerId = undefined;
    },150);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8CaRE/2/

(Vary the delay until you find something you're happy with - for me 150ms seems a reasonable setting in Chrome.)

Comment: +1 I like this approach the best but .. wouldn't you agree that the behaviour is better if you omit the conditional so the timeout is restarted each time the scroll event is fired?  http://jsfiddle.net/hmMeL/

Comment: @net.uk.sweet - yes, I agree. I actually had it with no conditional originally - can't remember why I changed, though I _think_ maybe I intended to have the conditional around the addClass only.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. Do you think setting the class unnecessarily on each scroll event could be a performance issue?

Comment: @net.uk.sweet: I've updated my answer to apply the conditional only to the addClass. It seems to run smoothly like that or with no conditional at all, but I figure it can't hurt to avoid unnecessary DOM access. If performance problems surfaced the first change I'd make would be to cache the jQuery object rather than getting a new reference every time.

Answer (score 0):

Probably isn't very healthy performance-wise, but you could add a `setInterval` to remove the class every few milliseconds combined with your `scroll` handler to add it when scrolling.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    $('body').addClass('scrolling');
});

setInterval(function() {
    $('body').removeClass('scrolling');
}, 100);​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pYVL8/

Or, slightly optimized:

```
setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].className = '';
}, 100);​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pYVL8/1/